# Sulu as a Pagebuilder: block within block

Tags: sulu

I want to use sulu as a pagebuilder.
A have a block with multiple elements in it. Now my next goal is to provide fields to sho a "Accordion-Script".

The Elements consist of

- title (text_line)
- content (text_editor)

I hoped that i could use a block in an other block like so:

```
<block name="contents"
           default-type="editor"
           minOccurs="0"
           maxOccurs="200"
           mandatory="true">
        <meta>
            <title lang="de">Artikelinhalt</title>
            <title lang="en">Contents</title>
        </meta>
        <types>
            <type name="tabs">
                <meta>
                    <title lang="de">Tabs</title>
                    <title lang="en">Tabs</title>
                </meta>
                <properties>
                    <block name="tabContents"
                           default-type="editor"
                           minOccurs="0"
                           maxOccurs="200"
                           mandatory="true">
                        <types>
                            <type name="tabContent">
                                <meta>
                                    <title lang="de">Texteditor</title>
                                    <title lang="en">Text editor</title>
                                </meta>
                                <properties>
                                    <property name="article" type="text_editor">
                                        <meta>
                                            <title lang="de">Inhalt</title>
                                            <title lang="en">Content</title>
                                        </meta>
                                        <params>
                                            <param name="table" value="true"/>
                                            <param name="link" value="true"/>
                                            <param name="paste_from_word" value="true"/>
                                            <param name="height" value="400"/>
                                            <param name="max_height" value="2000"/>
                                            <!-- CKEditor Parameters examples: -->
                                            <param name="extra_allowed_content" value="img(*)[*]; span(*)[*]; div(*)[*]; iframe(*)[*]; script(*)[*]" />
                                        </params>
                                    </property>
                                </properties>
                            </type>
                        </types>
                    </block>
                </properties>
            </type>
```

[...] here are my other type-attributes.

It does not work (backend is not loading the edit-page at all).
Is there a way to do that?

The Page should later be editable by the user and could have a structure like that:

```
- block
    - text
    - accordion
        - text
        - text
        - text
     - image
```

Comment: I have the same question - would be great, if blocks in blocks would be possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Sulu 2.1.0 nested block support has been added to the core, see the release notes here https://sulu.io/blog/sulu-release-2-1-0-2-0-9

Answer (score 0):

There is no support of nesting blocks in Sulu, but if I have a look at your example I would also say that it is not necessary to have nested blocks here.

It looks like you just want to group these blocks, therefore you could simply use a section:

```
 <section name="contents">
        <meta>
            <title lang="de">Artikelinhalt</title>
            <title lang="en">Contents</title>
        </meta>
        <properties>
            <block name="tabContents"
                   default-type="editor"
                   minOccurs="0"
                   maxOccurs="200"
                   mandatory="true">
                <types>
                    <type name="tabContent">
                        <meta>
                            <title lang="de">Texteditor</title>
                            <title lang="en">Text editor</title>
                        </meta>
                        <properties>
                            <property name="article" type="text_editor">
                                <meta>
                                    <title lang="de">Inhalt</title>
                                    <title lang="en">Content</title>
                                </meta>
                                <params>
                                    <param name="table" value="true"/>
                                    <param name="link" value="true"/>
                                    <param name="paste_from_word" value="true"/>
                                    <param name="height" value="400"/>
                                    <param name="max_height" value="2000"/>
                                    <!-- CKEditor Parameters examples: -->
                                    <param name="extra_allowed_content"
                                           value="img(*)[*]; span(*)[*]; div(*)[*]; iframe(*)[*]; script(*)[*]"/>
                                </params>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </type>
                </types>
            </block>
        </properties>
```

The sections are a pure visual help for the content manager, and won't have any effect on the structure passed to the twig template.

Comment: So my solution is not satisfying you?

Comment: It's not exatly what i thought about.
I need multiple "Tab-Elements" on one Page. The page is built by the customer vie one Block which i use as a pagebuilder.

For the moment i let him add multiple "tab" Elements in a row.
The template of the tab-Element checks if the previous element of the block was a tab element.

If it is not, then it starts a <section> (but doesn't close it).
If the next element of the block is no tab it closes the element.

This seems to be a bit hacky. But it works :-)

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here, but yeah, it sounds hacky. However, doesn't matter as long as it works :-)